# Warning "C++ requires a type specifier for all declaration" map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, deque

I am running this code in xcode .Why my compiler keeps on complaining for map assignment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

map<int,deque<int>> bucket;
deque<int> A{3,2,1};
deque<int> B;
deque<int> C;


bucket[1] = A;//Warning "C++ requires a type specifier for all declaration
bucket[2] = B;//Warning "C++ requires a type specifier for all declaration
bucket[3] = C;//Warning "C++ requires a type specifier for all declaration

int main() {

    for (auto it:bucket)
    {
        cout << it.first << "::";
        for (auto di = it.second.begin(); di != it.second.end(); di++)
        {
            cout << "=>" << *di;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

where as if I do the same thing inside main its works perfectly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

map<int,deque<int>> bucket;
deque<int> A{3,2,1};
deque<int> B;
deque<int> C;  

int main() {

    bucket[1] = A;
    bucket[2] = B;
    bucket[3] = C;

    for (auto it:bucket)
    {
        cout << it.first << "::";
        for (auto di = it.second.begin(); di != it.second.end(); di++)
        {
            cout << "=>" << *di;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output

```
1::=>3=>2=>1
2::
3::
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Is it something which I am missing .Not able to understand this behavior .
Any suggestion , help or doc .I looked in to similar question but didn't get satisfying answer

Comment: There is really no such thing as executable code outside of a function in C++.

Comment: deque<int> A{3,2,1};  why this worked ?

Comment: Because that is a declaration of a variable. That's where the idea of "executable code" gets a little fuzzy. The global variable has its constructor called, which in this case, is the initializer-list constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do something like this in global scope

```
int i;
i = 100;
```

because in C++11 you either initialize the value while declaration as in

```
int i = 100;
```

or set the value inside a function

```
int main() {
 i = 100;
}
```

Same is true with STL initialization also and that's the reason for your issue

Comment: bucket[1] = deque<int> A{3,2,1};
will the above work?

Comment: @HariomSingh Move the definition of `bucket` to after the `deque`s then you can use `map<int,deque<int>> bucket{{1, A}, {2, B}, ...};` All is good if you combine the assignments in with the initialization.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the three lines...

```
bucket[1] = A;//Warning "C++ requires a type specifier for all declaration
bucket[2] = B;//Warning "C++ requires a type specifier for all declaration
bucket[3] = C;//Warning "C++ requires a type specifier for all declaration
```

are statements. You cannot execute statements outside of a function in C (C is not Python). If you move those three lines of code inside of main() then it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do to initialize your variable outside of function scope is

```
std::deque<int> A{3,2,1};
std::deque<int> B;
std::deque<int> C; 
std::map<int, std::deque<int>> bucket {{1, A}, {2 , B}, {3, C}};
```

Answer (score -1):

The compiler recognises this code

```
bucket[1] = A;
bucket[2] = B;
bucket[3] = C;
```

as a [declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations) which shall have type specified, because you cannot run executable code (which invoking the [assignment operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_(C%2B%2B)) is) outside of the function (or as and initializer when declaring variable).
In cases of:

```
map<int,deque<int>> bucket;
deque<int> A{3,2,1};
deque<int> B;
deque<int> C;
```

`map<int,deque<int>>` and `deque<int>` are type specifiers.