# C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations memset(t, 0, sizeof(t));

Tags: c++, recursion, compiler-errors

I was doing a recursive question using memorization(the question can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gold-mine-problem/)). so I am creating a global array t with a max size of 100005*100005 and setting every value with -1 using memset but it is giving me the above error. why?

```
int t[100005][100005];
memset(t, 0, sizeof(t));
```

[here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/bc6d9e37-b5c6-4aca-ba4a-d53237e627fa) is my complete code.
How to avoid this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning "C++ requires a type specifier for all declaration" map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451081/warning-c-requires-a-type-specifier-for-all-declaration-map)

Comment: @NathanPierson okay, i understand why this is giving an error. but how to overcome this?

Comment: The call to `memset` needs to be inside a function.

Comment: Unless you have 4*9=36GB stack, the code won't run anyway. You can use `std::vector` provided you have enough RAM. EDIT: Oh, you declared it at global level, well, you will likely hit other limits with that.

Comment: Um, the code attempts to set every byte in `t` to 0; that's not needed, because that's what happens with global objects of builtin types. The question says that the goal is to set every value to -1; `memset` won't do that, because it sets every **byte**.

Comment: @PeteBecker: `memset` can do it, if you replace `0` by `0xff`.

Comment: @Kapil: do you just need to do this at the start of the program? If so, just move your `memset` call into `main` (or `WinMain` or whatever). But good luck allocating 80 Gb!

Comment: @TonyK -- that assumes a particular representation of negative values that is not required by the language (this may have changed recently).

Comment: @TonyK I tried that too, but it is still giving errors. I have provided full code, you can try it too.

Comment: @PeteBecker 1) C++20 requires two's complement 2) Realistically it doesn't matter because everything is two's complement anyway.

Comment: @KapilAgarwal, what can you mean? In the code at your link, the `memset` call hasn't been moved anywhere! If I do move it into `main`, it dies anyway (as expected) when asked to create an array containing 10 billion integers. Perhaps you need to re-think your approach?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili -- yeah, no big deal, we don't need to pay attention to standards, because we can just design based on assumptions about how everything works.

Comment: @PeteBecker well, yes you can dream of bizarre systems all day long with all pointer types being different in size, `CHAR_BIT` being 13, floating point numbers not being IEEE 754. People write code that runs on real hardware. No point in supporting non-two's complement systems since they don't exist anymore.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili -- [`CHAR_BIT` greater than 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091992/is-char-bit-ever-8).

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili -- frankly, I don't understand this insistence that writing non-portable code is inherently okay.It may well be that most folks won't run into systems where the non-portability bites them, but when it's straightforward to write portable code there's no reason to do it otherwise. `memset` should have no role in anything other than low-level bit banging.

Comment: @TonyK I did not change the code in the given link but I tried on my compiler and it was still giving errors so i said that, even you can check that too. And one more thing if you are talking about a billion number then let's take the size of t as 100*100 with taking an example of n=15 then **memset** still giving the same errors.

Comment: So post the code that is giving you these new errors!

Comment: @TonyK https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/611ae0dd-c16e-4655-b2ae-f1337b46bed6 is the link. I think the main problem is with _memset_ function Not with bigger number.

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake. Move that `memset` function into the `main` function, like I told you to! You said you'd tried it, but I don't believe you.

Comment: @TonyK It is getting too complex for both of us. It will work if I move that function to main. But my question is why *memset* is not working outside the function?

Comment: Didn't I answer "why *memset* is not working outside the function?" way back when I first flagged this as a duplicate? You said you understood why it was giving you an error.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well then, my answer is _read the manual_.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the right header so `memset()` is known to the compiler.

```
#include <cstring>
int t[100005][100005];
memset(t, 0, sizeof(t));
```

But why memset at all? C arrays can be initialized directly like this:

```
int t[100005][100005] = {{0, }, };
```

But lets go one step further and forget about C (and the parts of C that are part of C++) and learn modern c++ ways:

```
#include <array>
std::array<std::array<int, 100005>, 100005> t = {{{0, }, }};
```